# AG Grid displaying a blank chart Angular

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I have followed the tutorial on adding integrated charts to my data grid from here:
https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/integrated-charts-user-created/
However for me I'm getting the chart displayed with the axis but the chart is empty:[Blank chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JCIWF.png)

I'm fetching the data from a server and then rendering it on the grid.
My grid definition is as follows:
    `<ag-grid-angular #agGrid id="myGrid" class="ag-theme-alpine" [popupParent]="popupParent" [rowModelType]="rowModelType" [suppressServerSideInfiniteScroll]="suppressServerSideInfiniteScroll" [pagination]="true" [getServerSideGroupLevelParams]="getServerSideStoreParams" [rowGroupPanelShow]="rowGroupPanelShow" [columnDefs]="columnDefs" [defaultColDef]="defaultColDef" [autoGroupColumnDef]="autoGroupColumnDef" [columnTypes]="columnTypes" [rowData]="rowData" (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)" [rowSelection]="rowSelection" [enableRangeSelection]="enableRangeSelection" [enableCharts]="enableCharts" > </ag-grid-angular>`

I tried assigning the data type for the chart in the colDefs but that also did not work:

```
`constructor(private http: HttpClient, private dialog: MatDialog) {
this.rowData = [];
this.defaultColDef = {flex: 1, sortable: true, enableRowGroup: true};
this.columnTypes = {
  numberColumn: {
    editable: true,
    chartDataType: 'series',
    filter: "agNumberColumnFilter",
    valueParser: this.numberValueParser,
    filterParams: {
      buttons: ['apply', 'reset'],
      closeOnApply: true,
      suppressAndOrCondition: true,
      filterOptions: ['equals', 'lessThan', 'greaterThan']
    }
  },
  setFilterColumn: {
    filter: 'agSetColumnFilter',
    filterParams: {
      buttons: ['apply', 'reset'],
      closeOnApply: true,
      refreshValuesOnOpen: true,
      values: this.getSetFilterValues.bind(this)
    }
  },
  textFilterColumn: {
    filter: 'agTextColumnFilter',
    filterParams: {
      buttons: ['apply', 'reset'],
      closeOnApply: true,
      suppressAndOrCondition: true,
      filterOptions: ['contains']
    },
  }
};

this.columnDefs = [
  {
    field: 'entity',
    type: 'textFilterColumn',
    chartDataType: 'category',
  },
  {
    field: 'item',
    type: 'textFilterColumn',
    chartDataType: 'category',
    flex: 2
  },
  {
    field: 'customer',
    chartDataType: 'category',
    type: 'textFilterColumn'
  },
  {
    field: 'tx_number',
    flex: 1.5,
    chartDataType: 'category',
    // type: 'textFilterColumn',
  },
  {
    field: 'jan_2022',
    flex: 2,
    type: 'numberColumn',
    chartDataType: 'series',
    aggFunc:'Sum',
    headerName: 'jan_2022',
  },
}`
```

Comment: Have you tried assign data inside ngOnInit instead or constructor?

Comment: No, I will try that Thanks! can you tell me why this would work? Also can you point me to a resource for that? I'm new to angular.

Comment: Angular documentation https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks When you try to assign data inside the constructor, the component model properties are not bound yet. And nothing happens.

Comment: I tried moving it out from the constructor and I also found this: "Each custom Angular component must implement the agInit(params) lifecyle hook. AgInit is called by AG Grid before any of the Angular Lifecyle hooks, including ngOnInit. This order is deterministic and applies to all component types." from here - https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/components/
I can see that in the chart - the axis with charttypedata: category is coming but type as series is not being shown.